# Some fields of userinfo return empty Wechat API

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I use WeChat API to get user info, but some fields are empty ("nickname" is empty). This API has worked before 12/05/2022 but it's failed now. I don't know why we cannot get these values. Please help me take a look at this. Thank you so much.
https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/User_Management/Get_users_basic_information_UnionID.html#UinonId

[Link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmtDc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the WeChat official description, this method will no longer output avatar and nickname information after 12/27/2021.

Comment: Could you please link to this official description? There is nothing in the documentation.
Is there a different way to get these information?

Answer (score 1):

> 20230720 updates
> The way to do that obsoleted.Tt's new approach of getting userInfo:
> [wechat miniprogram 101: getUserProfile problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76714048/wechat-miniprogram-101-getuserprofile-problem)

Comment: docs:https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/component/button.html

Comment: Thanks taolu, following up with what OP asked (but got deleted), instead of showing the info on GUI, is there any way to retrieve the info and save them into local/global variable please? For you to answer this new followup Q, I've opened another Q at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76714048/. Thx.

Comment: _"And then you will get userInfo in "bindgetuserinfo" function"_, hmm, did you mean the `handleGetUserInfo` function instead?