# wechat miniprogram 101: getUserProfile problem

Tags: wechat-miniprogram

I'm trying with wechat miniprogram for the first time and I'm trying to port `getUserProfile` from https://github.com/Tencent/westore/blob/master/packages/westore-example/models/user.js
to https://github.com/discountry/weapp-weather/tree/backup

It works but its [`getUserProfile` functionality](https://github.com/Tencent/westore/blob/4bcdccc74853551e608745317d2e497ed1867cb6/packages/westore-example/models/user.js#L9) is not fully working ***for me***:

```js
    wx.getUserProfile({
      desc: '展示用户信息',
      success: (res) => {
        console.log('u.js getUserProfile success', this, res)
        this.userInfo = res.userInfo
        this.options.onUserInfoLoaded && this.options.onUserInfoLoaded()
      }
    })
```

Instead of getting the ***actual*** user info like this:

[image]

It only get a *fake* user info like this:

[image]

both the icon and the name ***are*** (retrieved) from API though.

[image]

I've been looking everywhere but cannot make out where the problem is. The wxml file content is a direct copy of working code:

```
  <view class="userinfo">
    <block wx:if="{{!userInfo.nickName}}">
      <button bindtap="getUserProfile">获取头像昵称</button>
    </block>
    <block wx:else>
      <image bindtap="bindViewTap" class="userinfo-avatar" src="{{userInfo.avatarUrl}}" mode="cover"></image>
      <text class="userinfo-nickname">{{userInfo.nickName}}</text>
    </block>
  </view>
```

Moreover, the following works, but I have no clue how it works, ie, the data and control flow:

```
  <text class="title">hello {{name}}</text>
  <button open-type="getUserInfo" bind:getuserinfo="buttonHandler">
    授权获取个人信息
  </button>
```

```js
  buttonHandler(event) {
    if (!event.detail.userInfo) return;
    this.setData({
      name: event.detail.userInfo.nickName
    });
```

So, Please

- correct the problem of the above `getUserProfile`
- and if you can explain (or give direct link to) how the above working code works a bit, it'd be really appreciated.

Comment: NVM, I tried to post an answer by quoting the official announcement (since posting merely a link would mostly be downvoted) , but I was blocked by https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340715/how-can-i-solve-the-body-cannot-contain-error-when-trying-to-post. So, I gave up.

Comment: WeChat official returned the rights of using users' nicknames and avatars back to the users themselves,now you can use input and button to get user's nickname and avatar.The input and upload-button need to set specail params to notice user choose their nickname and avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way about getting user's info changed 3 times in serveal years.Many developers complain about it.It trouble me too much at least modification.
User's avatar and nickname were used for illegal.So offical rule change frequently.

WeChat official returned the rights of using users' nicknames and avatars back to the users themselves.

It's the least method of getting user's avatar and nickname below:

```js
const defaultAvatarUrl = 'https://mmbiz.qpic.cn/mmbiz/icTdbqWNOwNRna42FI242Lcia07jQodd2FJGIYQfG0LAJGFxM4FbnQP6yfMxBgJ0F3YRqJCJ1aPAK2dQagdusBZg/0'

Page({
  data: {
    avatarUrl: defaultAvatarUrl,
  },
  onChooseAvatar(e) {
    const { avatarUrl } = e.detail 
    this.setData({
      avatarUrl,
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<button class="avatar-wrapper" open-type="chooseAvatar" bind:chooseavatar="onChooseAvatar">
  <image class="avatar" src="{{avatarUrl}}"></image>
</button> 
<input type="nickname" class="weui-input" placeholder="请输入昵称"/>
```

When user click the avatar-upload-button with ' open-type="chooseAvatar" ',a notice model with user's avatar option will show for choosing.If user don't want to use avatar of himself.He can upload other image.

As the same,while the input with ' type="nickname" ' get focus, wechat will notice user to input his nickname or input other content as special nickname for your application.

Notice:The avatar image which user uploaded is local file inseated net file.

Chinese documents only:https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/dev/framework/open-ability/userProfile.html

Comment: _"The way about getting user's info changed 3 times in several years.Many developers complain about it"_ and what's ironic is that most tutorials starts with just that, getting user's nicknames and avatars. It took me literally 2 days trying to figure out what's wrong, and I've already decided to give up. Thanks for the answer, which is the only approach available now, 头像昵称填写, Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: The officail documents update not timely in english.And least announcements use chinese only.I‘m trying to do something about correct the deviation like this and spreading in sometimes .But collecting doubt from most people is a problem.Perhaps,i can translate a series of wechat miniprogram tutorials.The tutorials will contrast to other PWA platforms. Thanks for some suggests.

Comment: That's OK. wechat miniprogram will be consumed mostly by Chinese speaking people I suppose, and having official documents in Chinese should not be a problem too. Translating them into other languages would be a problem down the road as such deviation as you mentioned will be inevitable in the future. So thanks for the offer but I think it is unnecessary personally, as long as you're still here answering question actively (and thanks again for that).